# Postgres restore from .dump file: Invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"

Tags: postgresql, heroku, psql

I've downloaded the latest copy of my heroku database with

```
$ curl -o latest.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url --app myapp`
```

And this gives a file with the following type on my local machine:

```
$ file db/latest.dump
    db/latest.dump: PostgreSQL custom database dump - v1.12-0
```

I'm trying to import this into my local Postgres DB (my_db) using psql.  However, I'm getting lots of errors:

```
$ psql my_db < db/latest.dump
    ...
    psql:db/latest.dump:119425: invalid command \?A~??ܣb?{#?+????LS??
    psql:db/latest.dump:119426: invalid command \D%!ѡ/F??g????A???dC????|2?M?$?8GTJ??c?E?;??֛Sh??S?[NP?f?2?+H?W????k
    ... [thousands of lines]
    psql:db/latest.dump:261719: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xba
```

The command `psql -f db/latest.dump my_db` fails the same way.

What needs to be done in order to import this file locally into a new database with the same schema, etc?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was able to use `pg_restore` to solve the problem:

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d my_db db/latest.dump
```

Comment: I don’t think you can use the backup file with `psql`: the Heroku “[backup file uses the custom format option in `pg_dump`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#export)”, and the “[custom-format dump is not a script for `psql`, but instead must be restored with `pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-LARGE)”.

Comment: BTW, if you were on a current PostgreSQL version, `psql` would've told you that you were trying to restore a custom-format dump and should use `pg_restore`.

Comment: @CraigRinger where would it have said that?  I'm using 9.4 and didn't see it.

Comment: @tyler Ah, might only do it for `psql -f dumpfile`. I *think* the patch made it into 9.4...